# Getting request attributes in freemarker

Tags: freemarker

How do I check a value from the request attribute in freemarker?
I tried <#if *${RequestParameters['servicesettings']} ??> but getting errors ->

Encountered "*" at line

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the Web application framework, because FreeMarker itself doesn't expose the request parameters. (Well, except if the framework uses `freemareker.ext.servlet.FreemarkerServlet` which is kind of an extension to FreeMarker.) Also, usually you shouldn't access request parameters directly from an *MVC* template, or anything that is HTTP/Servlet specific.

As of the error message, what you have written has a few syntax errors... probably you meant `<#if RequestParameters.servicesettings??>` (it's not JSP - don't use `${...}`-s inside FreeMarker tags). This will require that you have `RequestParameters` in the data-model, that I can't know for sure...

Comment: Got it, its working for me   try ->        Request.requestattribute; would return the request attribute and RequestParameters.somevalue for parameter..

Answer (score 1):

We should write like this:

```
${Request.requestattribute}
```

Comment: <#if RequestParameters.servicesettings??>

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
${requestParameters.servicesettings}.
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [JavaDoc of the `FreemarkerServlet`](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/api/freemarker/ext/servlet/FreemarkerServlet.html):

> It makes all request, request parameters, session, and servlet context attributes available to templates through `Request`, `RequestParameters`, `Session`, and `Application` variables.
>
> The scope variables are also available via automatic scope discovery. That is, writing `Application.attrName`, `Session.attrName`, `Request.attrName` is not mandatory; it's enough to write `attrName`, and if no such variable was created in the template, it will search the variable in `Request`, and then in `Session`, and finally in `Application`.

You can simply write:

```
${attrName}
```

to get the value of a request attribute (that you might have set in a servlet request filter using `request.setAttribute('attrName', 'value')`

Worked for me with Freemarker `2.3.27-incubating`